# Truncate text in bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, truncate

I am using the bootstrap col/grid system. How can I truncate the text inside the col so that it forces a single row ? I want my error message to be truncated so it stays on the same row as the buttons on its left (see image blow).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">

        <button class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="">Refresh</button>

        <div class="btn-group">
            <a ng-click="" class="btn btn-success btn-raised btn-sm">Build</a>
            <a  class="btn btn-success btn-raised dropdown-toggle btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">

            <div class="" ng-show="true" style="height:18px;">
                <span class=""><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <span class="">
                    <i>{{errorMessage}}</i> <!-- I want to truncate this so that a the buttons and the error message are on the same row ...-->
                </span>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I tried adding this on the div and span of the error message but it forced the text below the icon

```
.truncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: There is no `.truncate` class on any of the elements in your markup.  It would also be helpful to see all the CSS code acting on this markup as diagnosing the problem from a CSS excerpt may be impossible.  It would be great if you could set up a codepen demonstrating your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a 'max-width' to the element that holds the message, for your css to work. I.e.

```html
<i style="max-width: 80%;">My extremely long error message</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the same *height* and *line-height* to have just a line:

```
.truncate {
  line-height: 20px;
  max-height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use word-break ,

```
<style>
.truncate {
    word-break: break-word;
}
</style>
<span class="truncate">
                <i>{{errorMessage}}</i> <!-- I want to truncate this so that a the buttons and the error message are on the same row ...-->
            </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap 4 you can use the [text-truncate](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow) class.

```
<div class="text-truncate" ng-show="true" style="height:18px;">
    <span class="">
        <i>{{errorMessage}}</i>
    </span>
</div>
```